# Getting a vector of differences of a vector

Tags: r, vector

Suppose I have a vector `v` of length `n`; I wish to create a new vector of that length, that will contain `NA` in the first `k` cells, and that in cell number `m` it will contain the difference `v[m]-v[m-k]`.

I can create a for-loop that accomplishes that task:

```
diffs <- rep(NA, length(v))
for (i in k+1:length(diffs)) {
    diffs[i] <- v[i] - v[i-k]
}
```

But I've heard loops in `R` are slow, and it looks a bit cumbersome to do it like that.

Actually, my goal is to create a list of diff vectors and not a single one - one for each `k` in some range. Are loops the only solution?

## Example

On the input `v <- 1:5` and `k=2` I'd expect the output `[1] NA NA 2 2 2` (however, as it turns out, the output of my snippet above is `[1] NA NA 2 2 2 NA NA`...)

Comment: Could you provide an example of your vector v and how the final result would looks like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

?diff

```
vec <- data.frame(v=c(1,3,5,15,21))
vec$dif <- c(NA, diff(vec$v, lag = 1, differences = 1))

> vec
   v dif
1  1  NA
2  3   2
3  5   2
4 15  10
5 21   6
```

For other lag interval or magnitude of differences, change lag and differences arguments accordingly

Comment: Are you sure `lag` and `differences` are arguments of `c`?

Comment: @Bach No, they are not. Sorry.

Comment: Why have you decided to cast the vector into `data.frame` before doing the manipulation? It seems like `diff` can accept a vector as an argument as well...

Comment: @Bach. You mentioned vectors indeed but it was just a presentation option. It seems to be visually explicit.